# PHP XOR performance

Tags: php, performance, timing, xor

I am aware that XOR is the same as not equal, but I want to ask for the reason for the performance difference here. I know it is negligible, but I am curious to know why that happens.

### Analysis

My own tests:

```
$ php -r '$a=true; $b=true;
$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 0xFFFFFF; $i++) $a xor $b;
$end = microtime(true);
echo ($end - $start) / 0xFFFFFF;
2.8898769545694E-8
$ php -r '$a=true; $b=true;
$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 0xFFFFFF; $i++) $a !== $b;
$end = microtime(true);
echo ($end - $start) / 0xFFFFFF;
'
2.735811385077E-8
$ php -r '$a=true; $b=true;
$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 0xFFFFFF; $i++) $a != $b;
$end = microtime(true);
echo ($end - $start) / 0xFFFFFF;
'
3.2480544635878E-8
$ php -r '$a=true; $b=true;
$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 0xFFFFFF; $i++) $a xor $b;
$end = microtime(true);
echo ($end - $start) / 0xFFFFFF;
'
2.9041645487517E-8
$ php -r '$a=true; $b=true;
$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 0xFFFFFF; $i++) $a !== $b;
$end = microtime(true);
echo ($end - $start) / 0xFFFFFF;
'
2.7436373032351E-8
$ php -r '$a=true; $b=true;
$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 0xFFFFFF; $i++) $a != $b;
$end = microtime(true);
echo ($end - $start) / 0xFFFFFF;
'
3.2506237862734E-8
```

Average:

- `xor`: 28.9 ns
- `!==`: 27.4 ns
- `!=`: 32.5 ns

## I would like to ask:

Why do these operators have such significant performance?

I have actually done these tests a few more times, and `!==` is always faster than `xor`, and both are significantly (more than 10%) faster than `!=`.

Comment: Is that so significant? 1.5 ns difference in 28.9 ns isn't particularly different statistically

Comment: As I wrote: > I know it is negligible, but I am curious to know why that happens.

Comment: I'd imagine because they're doing different things..... `!=` and `!==` simply perform a comparison and return a new Boolean value for the result; whereas `xor` actually creates a new Boolean (the xored result) then tests that and returns a new Boolean again if that xored result is true/false

Comment: Doing a VLD check will show you what is happening in each case - https://3v4l.org/OLfo9/vld#tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLD output from PHP 5.6.0 for a simple test of the three options:

```
$a=true; $b=true;
$x = $a xor $b;

echo '-';

$a=true; $b=true;
$x = $a !== $b;

echo '-';

$a=true; $b=true;
$x = $a != $b;
```

gives

```
Finding entry points
Branch analysis from position: 0
Jump found. Position 1 = -2
filename:       /in/OLfo9
function name:  
number of ops:  16
compiled vars:  !0 = $a, !1 = $b, !2 = $x
line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  E >   ASSIGN                                                   !96, 
         1        ASSIGN                                                   !112, 
   4     2        ASSIGN                                           $5      !128, !96
         3        BOOL_XOR                                         ~6      $5, !112
         4        FREE                                                     ~6
   6     5        ECHO                                                     '-'
   8     6        ASSIGN                                                   !96, 
         7        ASSIGN                                                   !112, 
   9     8        IS_NOT_IDENTICAL                                 ~9      !96, !112
         9        ASSIGN                                                   !128, ~9
  11    10        ECHO                                                     '-'
  13    11        ASSIGN                                                   !96, 
        12        ASSIGN                                                   !112, 
  14    13        IS_NOT_EQUAL                                     ~13     !96, !112
        14        ASSIGN                                                   !128, ~13
        15      > RETURN                                                   1
```

So `xor` is indeed creating a temporary result that is subsequently freed

Answer (score -1):

I think that probably due to != is neglecting data type. Php processor need to convert both variable to the same data type in order to compare. 
Xor taking both variable as boolean,can compare directly without conversion.  !== will return false if the data type is different, also without conversion.

Comment: So your point is, data conversion is the main source of performance difference?